# recursive mkdir - folder exists but user has no permissions on it

Tags: linux, file-permissions, mkdir

I'm trying to recursively create directories through ssh.

The directory **/home/user/staging** exists. But the user has no permission to read **/home**. mkdir doesn't know if **/home/user** exists and tries to create it.

```
mkdir -p /home/user/staging/first/second/third/fourth/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user’: Permission denied
```

How to skip this directory and go on creating where user has permission?

I'm trying to do it with my own script,

```
rec()
{
    dir=$1
    if [[ ! -e $dir ]]; then
        echo "creating $dir"
        newdir=$(echo $dir | sed 's:/[^/]*$::')
        rec $newdir
        mkdir $dir
    fi
}
```

Fore some reason this check fails **if [[ ! -e $dir ]]**
and loop goes down past existing dirs and eventually doesn't create anything.

Comment: what would help: `id`; `ls -ld /home`

Comment: How about cd'ing into the user's home, then creating relative directories?

Comment: if `user` doesn't have execute permission on `/home`, then this is the expected behaviour. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13891/285436) about directory permissions might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to make this script work.

However, solution is to use --relative option of rsync itself.

```
rsync -a --relative /new/x/y/z/ user@remote:/pre_existing/dir/
```

As described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22908437/6505678